I can't connect to my mac port for Next.js app preview on mobile even using the ip address
my Next.js app is running on  http://localhost:3000, and my ip address is 172..., i tried connecting with my phone via http://172...:3000 but i got a message "Safari couldn't open the page because the server stopped responding."
i'm using macos 14.1.1  m1 chip
How do i resolve this?
Ps:it was working before, it suddenly stopped and i have tried using other mobile phones
i tried connecting to my mac port via local networt,
i was expecting it to render Next.js app

try reseting server

Also make sure your phone is connected on the same subnet (e.g wifi) as your computer. Maybe try to connect to the server from your mac using 172... instead of localhost and see what happens

@Xapadoan it is my phone providing the network, so on my mac using http://172...:3000 it works well. i cant figure out what wrong

@MeherKhurana i have reseted the server several
